# How to resolve "delete/modify" conflict caused by "git stash apply"

Tags: git

I recently did a `git stash`, then did some work on the branch and committed it, and got these errors when trying to do a `git stash apply`:

```
CONFLICT (delete/modify): app/controllers/orders_controller.rb deleted in Updated upstream and modified in Stashed changes. Version Stashed changes of app/controllers/orders_controller.rb left in tree.
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/models/product.rb
```

`git status` shows the following:

```
 $ git status
# On branch develop
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 16 commits.
# Unmerged paths: 
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   deleted by us:      app/controllers/orders_controller.rb
#   both modified:      app/models/product.rb
```

The file marked "delete/modify" was a new file that I added and hadn't yet committed before the `stash`.
I'd like to be back in the state I was in before the `git stash` -- having uncommitted local changes.  Can you suggest how to make that happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are popping the stash onto a different state; state that has one additional commit.   And worse, the commit has introduced merge conflicts, as you know.

You have two options:

1. pop that stash onto the latest commit and resolve the conflicts
2. pop the stash onto the prior commit.

Sounds like #2 is what you want to do.  Use:

```
    git stash branch new_branch [<stash>]  # <stash> will be the last one if not provided.
```

Comment: thanks. i just realized i did my 'stash apply' to the wrong branch.  Is there a way to undo the 'stash apply' on this branch?

Comment: Was the wrong branch clean before you did the 'stash apply'?  And, did do 'stash apply' or 'stack pop'?

Comment: it was clean, and I did 'stash apply'

Comment: So on the wrong branch do 'git reset --hard' which will remove all the local changes (in the working directory) introduced by the 'stash apply'.  Then you can checkout the original branch ('develop') from your question and follow my suggestion to apply the stash.

Answer (score 17):

This worked for me.

Do a-

```
git mergetool
```

Then you would be asked to pick the modified or deleted file or abort, and after this do one more time-

```
git mergetool
```

This would resolve the merge conflict and you can stash pop your changes.

Comment: I did not understand what does deleted file here means and deleted the stashed files now is that any way to recover them.

Comment: deleted files means deleted files, the files which you delete from your project

Answer (score 2):

In my case `git add <file>` helped:

Here is example https://gist.github.com/SgtPooki/10efd02b066a8704b776

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve the conflict!
Since you have updated the latest repository, the two files has been changed, project.rb and orders_controller.rb  has been modified in the latest repository. At the same time, your local change (stash) has also modified these two file, when you apply them, there will be conflict.

You need to solve the conflict in order to apply your local change.

For the first file, orders_controller.rb
the latest repo is deleted, do you want to keep it or not when you push your later commit?

For the second file, project.rb
you need to resolve the conflict in the file.